# How to create a graph from a given csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I was trying to create a graph from a csv file for a social network. csv file had 2 rows: Friend1, Friend2.

here, is my file graph.ipynb:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
Graphtype = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,  create_using=Graphtype)

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

It gave out error after running on jupyter :

```
KeyError: 'source'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5d8670ba64af> in <module>
      7 df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
      8 Graphtype = nx.Graph()
----> 9 G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,  create_using=Graphtype)
     10 
     11 nx.draw(G)
```

I am not able to solve this error.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to help without seeing the contents/format of the csv. You really need to make sure you csv file is of the same format expected by `nx.from_pandas_edgelist()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `nx.from_pandas_edgelist()`, you need to specify `source` and `target` parameters with valid column names. (Unless you have columns called `'source'` and `'target'`, in which case they will be selected as automatic defaults). See [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html).

Since we don't know what your `.csv` file looks like, I've taken the liberty of creating an example `df` to demonstrate.

Something like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline

# df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame({'friends':'jack', 'enemies':'jill'}, index=[1])

Graphtype = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'friends', 'enemies',  create_using=Graphtype)

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

I've now noticed you say *I was trying to create a graph from a csv file for a social network. csv file had 2 rows: Friend1, Friend2.*

If 'Friend1' and 'Friend2' are rows, then you need to transpose your dataframe so that they are columns:

```
df2 = df.transpose()
```

And then you should be able to set those columns as your source and target:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Friend1', 'Friend2',  create_using=Graphtype)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked without using the transpose(). looks like i was using from_pandas_edgelist inappropriately